# Multiple popups opened at the same time in OL3

Tags: javascript, popup, openlayers-3

I have some serious question. How can i set multiple popups to be opened at the same time? I am using this code to open a popup:

```
var container = document.getElementById('popup');
var content   = document.getElementById('popup-content');
var closer    = document.getElementById('popup-closer');

closer.onclick = function() {
  overlay.setPosition(undefined);
  closer.blur();
  return false;
};

var overlay = new ol.Overlay({
  element: container
});
```

And for viewing content for specific feature in cluster at specific coordinates i use this:

```
map.on('click', function (evt) {
  var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, 
                  function (feature, layer) { return feature; });
  var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
  var prop;
  var vyprop = "";
  overlay.setPosition(coordinate);
    var features = feature.get('features');
    for(var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
      prop = features[i].getProperties();
      vyprop += prop.odbermisto + "<br>";
    }
  content.innerHTML = vyprop;
});
```

Because it uses div as a content and moves it from coordinates, hwere it is needed, I ain't able to open two popups at the same time. is there any solution to do that, without duplicating and deleting divs, which i dont wanna do? Thx for help guys

Comment: See https://github.com/walkermatt/ol3-popup